# PreparedStatement with subquery returning empty result set

Tags: java, sql, prepared-statement

I've got a query that works fine when I run it in SQL Developer, but returns an empty result set when run as a prepared statement. I'm not sure if my query is formatted incorrectly, or if it's something else (which I'll leave for another question entirely).

So here is my query. I've stripped stuff out in order to capture the format of it, and not the business logic. The table has three columns: type, key, and value.

```
SELECT a.key id, a.value name
    FROM
        (SELECT * FROM sometable WHERE type='A') a,
        (SELECT * FROM sometable WHERE type='B') b,
        (SELECT * FROM sometable WHERE type='C') c,
        (SELECT * FROM sometable WHERE type='D') d
WHERE a.value = b.key
    AND a.value = c.key
    AND a.value = d.key
```

Essentially, *should* this execute correctly in a prepared statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you seeing any errors?

The query as is can be run as a [Statement](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html) since it is a static SQL.

Comment: Thanks. I figured out that something else was the issue (uncommitted insert statements). I'll give you cred for the response though.